# How to build a proper link with options in a View in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, hyperlink

Hi I am new in Zend Framework 1.12.
I want to build a link that simulates the same result than when I submit a form in Get method.

When I submit my form, the URL generated is `mysite.com/mymodule/mycontroller/myaction?steps%5B%5D=3`

How could I build that link in a View, except in that ugly way :

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('mymodule/mycontroller/myaction?steps%5B%5D=3'); ?>">
    My link
</a>
```

May be by passing an array on something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$this->url(array('action'     => 'myaction', 
                 'controller' => 'mycontroller', 
                 'module'     => 'mymodule', 
                 'steps[]'    => 3));
```

`$this->url()` is a [View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here a little solution to avoid the use of %5B%5D.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('mymodule/mycontroller/myaction?'.urlencode('steps[]').'=3'); ?>">
    My link
</a>
```